# python, how i do xml = '<start>%??</start>' % datetime.datetime

Tags: python, xml, datetime, parameters

is there any way to pass a datetime directly in this format?

```
mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
myxmldate = '<start>%??</start>' % mydate
```

or have i to pass like a string?
I need to pass to an xml a datetime structure.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [datetime.isoformat()](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)

```
mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
myxmldate = '<start>%s</start>' % mydate.isoformat()
```

Comment: Voting on this as it's far safer to use ISO formatting for date/time: it get's interpreted properly regardless of locale settings. To future proof (Python 3) the code, it would be better however to say (version 2.6 up):
`myxmldate = '<start>{}</start>'.format(mydate.isoformat())`

Answer (score 1):

Try to reed [for 2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date):

```py
>>> mydate.isoformat()
'2002-03-11'
>>> mydate.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
'11/03/02'
>>> mydate.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y")
'Monday 11. March 2002'
```

And for version 3 [Using type-specific](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) :

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 4, 12, 15, 58)
>>> '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(d)
'2010-07-04 12:15:58'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haveXML, it makes sense to use an XML parser. For example, with [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import datetime

mydate = datetime.datetime.now()
doc = ET.fromstring('<start>%??</start>')
for start in doc.xpath('//start'):
    start.text = start.text.replace('%??',str(mydate))

print(ET.tostring(doc))
```

yields

```
<start>2011-11-07 12:28:58.883274</start>
```